# How to simulate mobile environment with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobile

I want to simulate a mobile browser using `Node.js`, meaning that all mobile browser features should be available in the `JavaScript` side (on the client), even if they are mocked.

The webpages should *think* that they are loaded in a mobile environment. For instance, if we have a webpage which says:

```
if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
  document.body.innerHTML = "Mobile";
} else {
  document.body.innerHTML = "Not mobile";
}
```

...then when the page is loaded in the simulation, the body content should be `Mobile`.

What's the right way to do that? I'd avoid simply using PhantomJS (or anything similar) *and* executing a script which will do:

```
window.ontouchstart = function () {};
```

I was thinking to use [JSDom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), but it looks there's no easy way to just say `mobile:true` which would add all these properties.

What's the best way to create a browser which would have these `API`s exposed, simulating a mobile browser?

#### A better example

From the Node.js side I want to communicate with the browser emulation and get some results back. Let's assume we have an `index.html` page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        if ('ontouchstart' in window && window.orientation) {
          document.body.innerHTML = "Mobile";
        } else {
          document.body.innerHTML = "Not mobile";
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using [`node-horseman`](https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman) (which uses Phantomjs), we can do the following:

```
const Horseman = require('node-horseman');
const horseman = new Horseman();

const iPhone6 = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25";    

horseman
  .userAgent(iPhone6)
  .open('index.html')
  .evaluate(function () {
    return document.body.innerHTML;
  })
  .then(html => {
      console.log(html);
  })
  .evaluate(function () {
    return navigator.userAgent;
  })
  .then(ua => {
      console.log(ua);
  })
  .close();
```

This outputs `Not mobile`, while the user agent is the one I've provided (iPhone 6). Expected would be `Mobile`.

It simply shows that the `window.orientation` is not available, since it's not a mobile browser.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want node.js to simulate a mobile browser?  Since node.js is usually the server side of the equation, it is not obvious what you're trying to do?  Do you mean that you want to use node.js to make requests of some other site and you want that other site to think that the request coming from your node.js app is a mobile browser?

Comment: @jfriend00 Exactly! Generally, for *normal browsers* I've been using PhantomJS and Electron, but to simulate the mobile environment, I have no idea what could be the best way.

Comment: Please edit your question to state what exactly you're trying to do much more clearly.

Comment: @jfriend00 I added a tiny example. In short: I want to see what happens with a page loaded by a mobile browser, but doing that from Node.js (and obviously just emulating the features).

Comment: And, when you say simulate a mobile browser, what are you trying to accomplish with that simulation?  Worry about things like `'ontouchstart' in window` is client-side detection and is only relevant if you're going to actually run the javascript that comes back in the mobile page.  Are you trying to do that?  If you just want the server you're making the request to thinkk it's serving a page to a mobile browser, then you probably just need to set the right headers on the request (such as user agent) and support cookies (in case the site cookies you that it thinks you're mobile).

Comment: @jfriend00 Of course, I need a browser with JavaScript support which I can interact with from Node.js. Checking the user agent on the server is not enough. I did specify that I want to have the mobile browser features.

Comment: What does "interact with" from node.js mean?  This whole problem specification is too light on what you're really trying to accomplish.  Sorry, but I just don't get what you're really trying to do which limits my ability to understand the real problem and/or what solutions might work.

Comment: I don't really understand your question: if you're using either chrome or safari, you can either set the user-agent using safari (under devtools) to simulate iOS devices or, if you're in chrome, you can toggle the dev mode and choose the device you want to test: http://prntscr.com/dtae0q . Is this what you are looking for?... I mean, you are serving an application through node, aren't you?

Comment: @briosheje Exactly, but I want to do that programmatically.

Comment: @jfriend00 Working on a better example.

Comment: @IonicăBizău: then you might want to run iframes with different useragents. Alternatively, you will need to use a local proxy to simulate different user agents.

Comment: @briosheje Sorry, this is happening on the server. The user agent is a thing which should be controlled, but it's not enough.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've added a better example at the end of the question. Hope that makes it clearer what I want to do.

Comment: Testing for `window.ontouchstart` is not telling you whether you are in a "mobile" browser. I'm writing this with in a "desktop" browser, but this browser does provide `window.ontouchstart` because my laptop has a touchscreen.  Moreover, for "desktop" testing I've used browsers (through Karma and Selenium), `jsdom`, PhantomJS, and other solutions. There is no such thing a "the best one". There are solutions what work more or less well depending on the specific needs of the code being tested. I'm 100% certain the same holds true for "mobile" platforms.

Comment: @Louis Well, that was an example. What I really want to do is simply having a headless mobile browser, communicating with Node. It is up to the website developers how they check the platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mentioned Phantom and Horseman I believe you want a browser automation framework with mobile support. You can use selenium with chrome (ChromeDriver) instead of Phantom, and chrome supports mobile emulation.

Here you can find selenium client for NodeJS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver
chrome driver fo selenium: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Starting chrome in mobile emulation mode:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var capabilities = {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        mobileEmulation: {
            deviceName: 'Apple iPhone 6'
        }
    }
};

var driver = new webdriver
    .Builder()
    .withCapabilities(capabilities)
    .build();
```

Here you can find list of available devices: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41104964/893432

you can also define your custom device: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation

if you want it headless the latest chrome build supports it:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md

You can also run your test on a real android device or emulator using selenium:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started/getting-started---android

Comment: This looks good, but I'm afraid this won't work on a server without GUI.

Comment: @IonicăBizău As I mentioned you can run chrome in headless mode: http://www.chrisle.me/2013/08/running-headless-selenium-with-chrome/ and https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/5336747

Comment: That's even better! Is it possible to run Android in headless mode in a similar way? Thanks!

Comment: @IonicăBizău You can run the android emulator in headless mode https://paulemtz.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-testing-in-headless-emulator.html then connect to its chrome using selenium!

Comment: Thanks. Can you add the steps to setup this environment? Sounds not a simple task, and that post is 4 year old.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Nothing has really changed since then, just download the android SDK for your platform, create an AVD and then run it in the background. If you're new to android emulator you better first install and experience it in a graphical environment https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html

Comment: ok i simply checked going here `https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent` using `await driver.get('https://...')` by selenium-webdriver, but nothing seems changed...seems that this does not work anymore. Do you know if something is changed @Ali ?

Comment: Ok I found a solution: `var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
.forBrowser(‘chrome’)
.setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options()
.setMobileEmulation({deviceName: ‘Apple iPhone 5’})
//.setMobileEmulation({deviceName: ‘Google Nexus 5’})
//.setMobileEmulation({deviceName: ‘Google Nexus 7’})
.addArguments(“start-maximized”)
.addArguments(“test-type”)
)
.build();`
The list of supported devices is the list you can find on devTools->toggle device toolbar button->click on device name->edit...->here's the list.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update in 2021:

To use emulation mode with selenium-webdriver, now the right way to do it is:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
.forBrowser('chrome')
.setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options()
.setMobileEmulation({deviceName: 'Apple iPhone 5'})
//.setMobileEmulation({deviceName: ‘Pixel 2 XL’})         //<--- tested
//.setMobileEmulation({deviceName: ‘Google Nexus 7’})
//.addArguments('start-maximized')
)
.build();

//Rest of the operations will be done in emulation mode
// this links shows what user agent you are currently using
driver.get('https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent');

driver.quit();
```

Comment: 1. You need to declare chrome `const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');` 2. You need to change name from `Apple iPhone 5` to `iPhone 5`